# I cannot access proxy of a running docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a running Docker container which shows PORTS 9191/tcp. So on my browser, I tried accessing server using localhost:9191/api/.... However, browser throws an error `This site can’t be reached`

Here is a log to docker ps 

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c214aefed15e        shah                "youtube-dl-server -…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        9191/tcp            boring_swirles`

This is what my docker file looks like

`FROM mariozig/youtube-dl_server
RUN pip install --pre youtube_dl_server
EXPOSE 9191
ENTRYPOINT ["youtube-dl-server", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not mapped the docker container port to host port.

The docker container runs on a host. And The host doesn't know which requests to be directed to the docker container. For that you have to to map the host port to docker container port using `-p` flag in `docker run` command as shown below:

```
docker run -d -p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT IMAGE_NAME
```

`-p` in this command will specify that you are forwarding your host port to the container port. In your local host in the port `HOST_PORT` will call the port `CONTAINER_PORT` of your container.

Now when you will access the `HOST_IP:HOST_PORT` then the host will redirect the request to corresponding container with which this HOST_PORT has been mapped.

For example I started a tomcat docker container and mapped the tomcat container's 8080 port to host's 9092 port by using the above command. When I do docker ps I can see the mapping under `PORTS` as `0.0.0.0:9092->8080/tcp`

Comment: Thank you. The command helped me solve the issue. Now that it's solved I remember I did come across this issue in past. However, I still have a confusion. I thought the order of the argument passed while running the image does not matter. But in this case the order of the argument passed to docker run matters. This fails ``docker run suprit-dl -p 8080:9191`` but this solves the issue ``docker run -d -p 8080:9191 shah`` Using the name of an image before fails but using at the end solves the issue.

Comment: As per https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ the command is `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
`. So all the flags like -p or -d or -it etc. has to be before image name. After image name you can pass the command. So order does matter.